# Magento - Convert Attribute Label to Attribute ID outside of product loop

Tags: php, magento, attributes

I'm trying to get the id of an attribute that I know the label of outside of a product loop. Basically I just want to convert the label to the ID.

The attribute code is new_brands and the label is TESTONE I'm trying to get it's ID which I know to be 250.

I've called a category the attribute label (TESTONE) and stored this in a variable like this

```
$brandname = Mage::registry('current_category')->getName();
```

With that information I want to convert the label TESTONE to it's ID but outside the product loop.

The purpose is I'm building a custom template for a brands page which will use the id in a filter like this

$collection->addFieldToFilter(array(

```
    array('attribute'=>'pos_brands','eq'=>$brandid),array('attribute'=>'new_brands','eq'=>'250')
));
```

Otherwise I'd be happy with a solution that worked in reverse. i.e. got the label from the ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i understood your attribute is a dropdown (`$entityType = "catalog_product", $attrCode = "new_brands", $withEmpty = false`):

```
$data = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')
  ->loadByCode($entityType, $attrCode)
  ->setSourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_source_table')
  ->getSource()
  ->getAllOptions($withEmpty);

$set = array();
foreach ($data as &$row) {
  $set[$row['label']] = $row['value'];
}
var_dump($set);
```